# Target emails based on contacts near a postal code

Tags: civimail

I am moving over to CiviCRM from The Action Network and am wondering if email blasts can be targeted by inputting a location (postal code or city) and choosing a set number of kilometers surrounding it to include. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#proximity-search then from the actions dropdown create a group or smart group out of the results and use the group in your mailing.